# Visual C++ 2010 iterator "reset"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, iterator

I have this situation:

```
/// FILE A.h
class A {
     // Contents.
};
typedef std::vector<A> vA;
typedef vA::iterator   vAIt;

/// FILE B.h
#include "A.h"
class B {
     // Contentes
     vAIt m_ItToMyObject;
     void Zero(void)
     {
          // Contents set to "zero"
     }
};
```

As you can see, B class holds an iterator to a vector vA, and also a function named "Zero" which is meant to set all member variables to zero or similar (clear for vectors, empty for strings and so on) and obviousy does not have any access to vA.

My question is: is there a way to be absolutely sure that m_ItToMyObject will be vA.end()? Something like nullptr for pointers.

Comment: Why not let the class store a reference to the vector?

Comment: I'm converting very old code: I'm not sure I can do that easily.

Comment: The end() function is an *instance* function, not static.  So `vA.end()` makes no sense.  As long as your B class *encapsulates* a private object of type vA then you can make sure that the iterator has a predictable value.  You did not show one so it is just a wild guess right now.

Comment: B knows nothing about vA. Originally it was a pointer to array element, so I made a workaround to make it working.